# able to fold and unfold, but how to toggle html text when folded and unfolded. (such as view replies/hide replies)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

currently I'm able to fold and unfold comment replies, but when I unfold it, it still says view replies. I want this to be changed to hide replies. how do I achieve this?

```
 <a href='#' class='replies'>           
         view{{comment.comment_count}}replies</a>
<script>
$('.replies').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".got_replies").fadeToggle(); 
})
$(".got_replies").fadeToggle(); 

</script>
```

I have no idea how to do this...can someone gives me some hint?I don't think this will be too complicated job but don't know how to even start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some text manipulation

```
 $('.replies').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next(".got_replies").fadeToggle();
    text =  $(this).text();

    if(text.indexOf('view') >= 0) {
       text = text.replace('view','hide');
    } else {
     text = text.replace('hide','view');
    }
     $(this).text(text);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnq5ba4t/

Comment: thanks I think I now know what to do, by the way I tried your code on mine but it displays replies unfolded when I refresh the page and says hide. when I refresh the page, the replies need to be folded and say view

Comment: this will not save the state of the text after page refersh

Comment: save the state to localsesion/cookie

Comment: there's gotta be a better solution no? I'm googlling and there are so many solutions but none of them work in my case

Comment: better than cookies or localstorage?